# Using "Sign in" vs using "Log in"

Tags: terminology, copywriting

Is there any research in this area, it seems "Sign in" is more common and hence more recommended.

Comment: I rather use `Log in/out` and `register` instead of `Sign in/out` and `Sign up`. The `Sign xx` notation seems confusing to me.

Comment: It's really hard for a non native english speaker to distinct sign up/sign in/sign out so I'd suggest to go for sign up/log in/log out.

Comment: Any updates to this topic for 2014/2015 ?! 
Additionally,  Based on latest research/work, when is it best use Log In/ Log Out vs. Sign In / Sign Out for enterprise SaaS software?

Comment: I prefer to eliminate the process entirely. 

Unless you're maintaining something that is of value *to the user* over a series of visits, you should be able to work around and many times eliminate "creating an account".

Answer (score 264):

In "[Homepage Usability](http://www.useit.com/homepageusability/)", Jakob Nielsen (together with Marie Tahir, 2002, p. 53) **recommends the use of "sign in" / "sign out" over "log in" / "log out"**. This is empirically based on a survey of several large-scale websites and thus supports OP's "more common" argument.

Furthermore, I second [@Dan Barak](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in/1081#1081) in that you should use "Register" or "Join [your-service-here]" as opposed to "sign up" in order to avoid unnecessary confusion. (I cannot recall whether Nielsen and Tahir had any recommendations regarding *this* issue, though.)

Comment: I agree there is confusion with the `Sign in` and `Sign up`, I rather use `register` instead.

Comment: I guess the survey was targeted to english native speakers, because phrasal verbs are by far the most difficult thing to grasp for foreigners. To me, the difference between sign up and sign in is small.

Comment: "and thus supports OP's "more common" argument." What does OP stand for?

Comment: @TimFitzGerald Original poster; E.g. the person who asked the question.

Comment: Great answer, but I wonder whether there's a more recent research, since Nielsen himself admits that some usability recommendations change over time.

Comment: Agreed with @Yosef... The source quoted was from 2002, when the internet was just a baby.

Comment: I think "common use" is a pretty poor argument here. Plenty of UX antipatterns are in common use, with the better alternatives represented far less. It's quite possible that designers use "sign up/sign in", because they like the symmetry, but that it it increases the cognitive load and probability of capture slips.

Comment: I think the issue of using human language rather than system language is a factor here.... log in is a very terminal focussed language. Sign in though...more standard even away from computers

Comment: While convention is worth considering in terms of user expectation, it would be of greater benefit to the customer to present accurate terms. As the customer is not adding to a "log", they are simply identifying themselves at a port of entry, "_Sign_ In" would be the more accurate term, balanced with "Create Account" - which combined provide a clear description of both options and whilst easily disambiguating the two, presenting a clear and guided path for the customer.

Comment: I think this answer is outdated as the industry seems to use login more than sign in

Comment: @BrunoLM Google uses Sign In, and then Create an account if you click sign in but don't have an account already

Comment: Jakob Nielsen is currently using "Log in" over "Sign in" on his own website.

Answer (score 68):

While I don't have a very strong opinion here, I would bear in mind:

- **Sign In** and **Sign Up** are quite close.
  Users might click one instead of the other sometimes.
  Either you make the difference more evident by location or graphics, or you could also use "Register or "Join" instead.
- Make sure you stay consistent with the log out vs. sign out.

Comment: Dan's answer is pretty complete, but I'd add one more detail: "Log in" is a valid verb where "Login" is a valid noun. "Signin", however, isn't a valid noun. On the other hand, "Signup" and "Sign up" have the same relationship, and if you use "Log in", you'll probably use "Register" as opposed to "Sign up". Then there's also "Log on" and "Logon", and of course "Log off" or "Log out". Errrr.

Comment: @Rahul I really appreciate the differentiation between "Log In" and "Login" here. For years, I thought both are the same thing.

Answer (score 39):

I think that this [article about the “Sign Up” button](http://www.gkogan.co/blog/stop-asking-me-to-sign-up/) is interesting, the author **changed the “Sign Up” button to “Try it Free”** and **clicks increased by 212%**.

His thesis is that the standard “Sign Up” buttons don’t work because “**they ask for blind commitment**” and “**do not offer any value**”.

Visitors also “see common elements repeated on many sites” and “they begin unconsciously ignoring those elements (aka “habituation”)”.

He suggests:

> - **Tie it to your product.** If you have a SaaS for trading bitcoins:    “Start Trading Bitcoins.” If you have a marketplace for artists: “Start Selling Art.” This helps prevent the button from being overlooked.
> - **Give, don’t take.** “Get Access” and “Sign Up” both lead to the same thing, but one makes the visitor feel they’re getting something, while the other doesn’t.
> - **Compel people to act.** Use action verbs such as get, start, and try.

Of course there are many variables to consider (what kind of website is yours? Changing the label of the button increases clicks, but what about new subscriptions? etc.) but it may be worth having a look at it.

Comment: This is interesting but it doesn't directly answer OP's question.  The question was about Sign in vs Log in, not Sign up.

Comment: I'm way less likely to sign up for something if it says "try it free", because that implies I will either have to pay later, or am not getting access to the full site

Answer (score 22):

Here's a good overview on how a few popular sites are using Sign in, Log in etc.
[Login/Logout vs Sign In/Sign Out vs Log in/Sign out – A short roundup](https://web.archive.org/web/20130416031325/http://0xtc.com/2009/06/25/login-logout-vs-sign-in-sign-out-vs-log-in-sign-out-a-short-roundup.xhtml/)

Comment: Interesting that most of their URLs go to /login even though the words of the link say "Sign In".  I suppose /sign_in is a little unwieldy as a url.

Comment: Or perhaps the developers think in terms of "log in" but the interface designers think in terms of "sign in."

Comment: Since the server seems to be down: [cached archive.org version](https://web.archive.org/web/20130416031325/http://0xtc.com/2009/06/25/login-logout-vs-sign-in-sign-out-vs-log-in-sign-out-a-short-roundup.xhtml/)

Answer (score 20):

### Use *Log in* to avoid capture slips

I would be very careful with the "common usage" argument. For example: the use of *sign up* and *sign in* has a very pleasant symmetry which doubtless appeals to many people. Unfortunately, this symmetry reduces the difference by which the user recognizes the button she needs to just two letters. **It's very easy to click sign *up* when you meant sign *in***.

Ultimately, the fact that everybody does it, doesn't mean that it's good UX. There's plenty of terrible UX patterns that are conventions. (Confirmation dialogs, anyone?)

For the reasons above, I would not use any option with *sign* in it: even if you go with "sign up/log in", the fact that it's so close to "sign in" means the user has to pay more attention, even if she makes the right choice in the end.

If you use "register/log in", there is no chance of confusion, and you lighten the cognitive load.

Comment: Similarly, if you use `register` / `sign in` you avoid confusion, but you *also* fit common usage.

Comment: The suggestion to use "Log" is based on a conflation between "Sign *up*" and "Sign *in*". While there does exist such a confusion, it is not a valid argument to prefer "Log" in this case.

Comment: @cleverbit My point is that there is only one action for the "log" prefix (no such thing as logging up). Therefore a link starting with log will never be mistaken for a registration link.

Answer (score 12):

I agree consistency is key.

This means not just consistent within your own site but with the general web (if it's a web based app)

I believe you can't be too far from the 'norm' following the example of google, yahoo, etc.

Google: Sign Out, Sign In, "Create an account"

Yahoo: Sign Out, Sign In, "Sign up for a new account"

Answer (score 11):

Just on a gut feeling - I would rather prefer using "Sign in", "Sign out" and "Register/Join/Create account" variation over "Log in".

Mostly because "Logging" something does not really convey the meaning of "entering" quite the same way as "sign in" does.

I can log any daily event, but that is just a mention of a fact while when I sign in at the door of an office building, I am giving my signature that I have entered the building and when I "sign out", I am also recording the fact that I am leaving the building...

Comment: +1 - I would also go as far as to say that it 'sounds' a little bit more secure to "sign" into something; people are quite used to signing things safely in the real life.

Comment: On the contrary. **Logging in** is exactly what we do when we enter our credentials on a website. We actually make an entry into the *log* before entering the system. @Ronal Tepp's answer is exactly what the answer *shouldn't* be.

Comment: Oh @ShreyasTripathy, you are so sure that one way of expressing this concept is so much superior to the other, that you are ready to crucify anybody holding an opposite opinion... Really constructive ...

Comment: I have nothing against your opinion because there aren't any specific rules for using these keywords. My qualm is with the logic behind your answer

Answer (score 10):

I personally prefer the Log In / Sign Up combination. My justification for this is that the Sign In and Sign Up will confuse people, it becomes harder for them to find what each button means unless they reach the end of the word.

Log In is pretty standard and gets the job done and takea away the confusion as well.

Answer (score 8):

As a fairly old Englishman I've grown up understanding that signing up meant you were entering some kind of contract requiring your signature. Often these contracts or agreements had some legal obligations attached so when ever I see "Sign up" it makes me nervous.

On the other hand ,"Sign in", to me means something completely different only used to indicate a visit. No legal or binding connections.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [google trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=sign%20in,login), **"login" is used 9 times more than "sign in"**.

Nevertheless, there are **two countries** that **prefer "sign in"** over "login": **France** and **Turkey**.

"sign in" is used 50% more than "log in".

[image]

"log on", "logon" and "sign on" are not widely used.

Although Jakob Nielsen recommended in 2002 the use of "sign in" / "sign out" over "log in" / "log out", the dialog principles of the ISO 9241-110 norm recommends that design should be in conformity with user expectations. In other words: if everyone is doing it, you should also do it.

Another important dialog principle is the error tolerance. Having "login" and "sign up" will avoid capture slips as recommended in [Peter's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/83889/133566)

**In summary:** Use "Login" for the title of your pages and links,
"Log in" in the buttons to log in
and "Sign up" to create a new user account.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no definitive answer to this.

**It really depends on your demographic.**

If your demographic understands what Sign in is, it's ok. However, there is a case in my home country where the majority of people don't understand what "Sign in" means. The "Log in" is much better understood. So when I changed the button to "Log in" and the users of that country specific website started to log in more often.

**So the answer is use "Sign in" as a best guess used by Google/Yahoo, but check if you demographic does not confuse it and understands it well.**

If the people in your country do not understand it well use "Log in"

Answer (score 2):

In light of the fact that there's so much subjective opinion on this topic, I'd like to call for standardization, perhaps by W3 as part of their WCAG accessibility guidelines. The lack of a standard makes this a real problem for blind and vision impaired users who typically use a search tool to find the login link (or button). Having to search in turn for "sign in", "log in", "signin", and "login" (all of which I've personally seen) is frustrating and time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Since neither users nor sites really think about the action as signing or logging, "Authenticate" may be a useful alternative.

Comment: But do users think of themselves as 'authenticating' when they're signing in to a website? I would have thought that this is even further down the list of things people think of doing than 'signing' or 'logging' are.

Comment: I personally think of the process as authentication (as opposed to authorization or signing), so there is at least one. The other terms are only familiar through previous presentation in this context. Signing your name at the end of the form is not analogous as it is for authorization, not access. Some OS settings, mobile apps, and bank sites have even switched to a "lock" metaphor. You essentially unlock (and sometimes authorize as well) through authentication.

Comment: The process of authentication almost feels like it is being tied into the log in/sign up flow these days (at least with certain types of applications).

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same dilemma as well. In this instance, we're really isolated ourselves to English.

I ultimately took the shortest route by using Log In for http://simmerwp.com. "Log" is shorter than "sign" so that's what I let my decision ride on ultimately. As you point out, many social networks and other platforms use "Sign," and others use even more (longer) outlandish copy.

I think the placement, and icon selection are almost more important than the text, however. In the instance above you can see we went for a super minimalist design in the main navigation at full responsive width, and down around tablet and mobile widths, we have a single icon to combine these areas.

Cheers, and good luck!

*Edit: To be honest, I don't know why we're not using just "Login" vs. "Log In," the former being shorter still. Welcome to any thoughts on that spelling as well.*

Answer (score 1):

The term 'log in' is, from what I see, considered somewhat 'antiquated' - When a few people  I know hear the phrase log in, they claimed they first thought of the windows 95/98 log in screen.

I believe that it is just a stylistic change of no real importance.

Personally, I prefer 'log in', but then again I also use a beige telephone and an IBM keyboard that *predates* windows 95/98. So take that with a pinch of salt. I am of the impression that it is now seen as antiquated, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with Log in is there is no Log up. You have to either use Create Account, Join or Sign up anyways. My thinking is that Login, Logout is mostly used in Desktop software and Sign up and Sign in look mostly website related.

However, I myself use Sign up and Sign in in my desktop software because it seems US population is used to mostly Sign up and Sign in.

Another confusion is between the use of 'Login' or 'Log in'. 'Sign up' and 'Login' makes sense too. However, in my view, Logout is better than Sign out for desktop software.

Comment: This question isn't about what to call the registration link, but... I would not use both "Sign In" and "Sign Up" since they're so similar. I've seen users click the wrong one and get errors upon submission. The difference between "Sign In" and "Register" is easier to see at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use "login", "sign out", and join. In my opinion, "join" is easier to distinguish than "sign up," and sounds better than "register". I would use "login" and "sign out" because I see them used more commonly than "sign in" or "log out". They are also easy to use and distinguish. **This website even uses "Log In" and "Sign Up"!**

Answer (score 1):

*Log in* is most popular.

I recently checked 100 SaaS landing pages, and out of those, 48% used *Log in*. The single-word *Login* was also used by 13% of the sites, surprisingly enough, though since it's technically a noun, the two-word *Log in* is still likely better.

*Sign in* was the second most popular, used by 35% of sites.

And sentence case was more popular, but that or title case work equally well—just keep it consistent.

*source (and more UX micro copy standards from the survey): https://reproof.app/blog/ux-copy-survey*

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use "sign in" or "log in" as opposed to "login", I don't think it really matters that much. Users understand both terms equally well from the results I've seen. I've never seen a person confused with where to log in when it says either term.

Definitely be consistent with log in/out or sign in/out either way. I'd also use register instead of sign up unless you have a good reason to use the latter; sign up and sign in are very similar at a glance.

Before anyone says anything about it in comments on this, login (and logon, logoff & logout) is bad because it is an adjective, not a verb. You don't login, you log in on the login page.

Comment: @Rahul already made this comment to @Dan Barak's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a way of saying mostly.
Logs are basically defined as  "record of observations" so by logging in it defines to check your credentials from a log.
Sign in on the other hand sounds more sophisticated but less trendy.

The choice ultimately is  yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sign up means "to register; to create an account". In computing, sign in and log in are synonyms. Both mean "to open a session with an account that is already created". There is one difference: the derived noun login "a username; a session under that username" exists, but there is no such noun as *sigin

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, We may use "Sign In" when a user "Signed" an agreement while registering to a website while on the "Sign up" Section. This means you hearby sign and enter the system.

Whereas "Login" says Ok create my Log and let me enter into the system.

I havent read any articles on this, this is just a wild guess as the names say it all.

Comment: this isn't the place for wild guesses and no research

Comment: My bad. Will come up with more authenticate references to this very soon.

Answer (score -3):

How about "Authenticate" and "Terminate Session"?

Comment: Why these terms? Are they well known? Do users respond well to them? Are they in common use? We'll need more information as to why you're suggesting these options.

Comment: Those are accurate and widely used terms for software developers. Which is why I recommend that developers read *The Inmates Are Running the Asylum: Why High Tech Products Drive Us Crazy and How to Restore the Sanity* http://www.amazon.com/The-Inmates-Are-Running-Asylum/dp/0672326140

Comment: i can't actually think of anything worse from a users perspective short of using hex codes or something !

Comment: I'm just laughing at the poor guy's username.

Comment: Did ... did he create the username to answer this question?