# When to use "join," "register," or "sign up"?

Tags: terminology, login, copywriting, registration

For a user, when is it better to be asked to do the following:

1. "Sign In" vs. "Log in"
2. "Join" vs. "Register" vs. "Sign Up"
3. "Sign Out" vs. "Log out"

Different websites seem to use them differently, and I wonder if there are strategic occasions for each?

Comment: For "Sign In" vs. "Log In", see http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Log in / out is more technical sounding than sign in / out.  That said, I don't think there is any confusion with either one of them.  The last time I looked at major sites using log v. sign it was a pretty even split between them.  I would opt for **sign in / out** simply because it is more human speak.

Regarding Join, Register and Sign up.  They each have slightly different meanings language wise, although even here I doubt that it will be critical.

For my (arguably subjective) take on their meanings:

- **Join** is when it's a club.  You join a rowing club.
- **Register** is used when you are simply adding your details to some system for future use or access.  You register to vote.
- **Sign up** usually has the connotation of a service or conference.  You sign up for the military, or sign up for this conference.

The best thing that you can do is to **ask a representative sample of your audience** what  is clearer and more human to them.  Then go with that.

Edit: Something to consider is using "Sign up" and "Log in" as they are further apart visually and faster to scan than using "Sign up" and "Sign in".

Comment: +1 very good answer :) I want to add that I personally prefer "login"/"logout" because I feel I know exactly what i'm doing by clicking it. It's a little more technical, yes, but it gives me a small sense of trust.

Comment: It's interesting that "log in" sounds more technical. I've always thought of "log" as being analogous to the log I have to sign when I arrive at my doctor's office. Sign in and log in are exactly the same in that context: you have to sign the log to let them know who's waiting. That said, "sign in" is the more natural expression for that action for me, but I wonder if there are places (or situations? occupations?) where "log in" would be more common.

Comment: Sign In is more so used when going to an actual in real life event, and they ask you to sign in. Log in is for websites.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that "Sign up" and "Sign in" are visually very close.  I find that combo confusing and for that reason avoid using if possible

Comment: +1 for *`"Sign up" and "Log in" as they are further apart visually and faster to scan than using "Sign up" and "Sign in".`*

Comment: > simply because it is more human // Well, if human means US citizen, all right then.

Comment: @batisteo What about that implies being a US citizen?  It's common English language usage in the UK, Ireland, South Africa, Australia, New Zealand, Canada, and the USA.

Answer (score 31):

As a non-native english speaker, I always have found **sign in** & **sign up**, VERY confusing, I always click the wrong button. You should avoid Sign up. Login and Logout are not so much confusing

Comment: Except that both _login_ and _logout_ are nouns and signifies procedures, whereas we are talking about an action; thus, verb phrases. In your case, would be to _log in_ and to _log out_. Interestingly, we _log on / off_ a computer or network. However, Microsoft were the first who introduced _log in_ and _log out_. My guess is that some UX designer were confused with the verb phrases _lock in_, _lock out_, _lock on_, _lock off_, and _lock up_.