# When should "Log on" or "Log off" be used?

Tags: website-design, login, authentication, signup-signon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using “Sign in” vs using “Log in”](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in)

I'm porting an old application that has a "Log on" screen.  When would I use "Log on" vs the alternatives (Sign In / Log In)?

Comment: See this very similar question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in

Comment: @JonW - Similar? I'd say it's an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

There is some evidence that `Sign In` and `Sign Out` are generally more readily understood than the alternatives, so if you have the opportunity *you should change it*.

There is some relevant discussion and links to research on this similar question: [Using "Sign in" vs using "Log in"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in)