# For enterprise web-based software, which is best Log In/ Log Out vs. Sign In / Sign Out

Tags: login

The last time this question was asked on this platform was 3-4 years and not specific to enterprise SaaS ago, so it's time for an update as our field moves quickly.

Based on latest research/work, when is it best use Log In/ Log Out vs. Sign In / Sign Out for enterprise SaaS software?

Comment: Please link to the original question on UX StackExchange...  I'm not sure that Enterprise changes anything in the resolution of the question.

Comment: Original post I was referring too: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in

Comment: Hmm I am not sure why this is a different question, because I can't think of anything specific to enterprise that would cause the original question to be different. "We need an update"  is not a valid reason to post a duplicate question because it unconstructively splits search results and the community's attention.  Would you consider either clarifying why this question is different, or deleting it and either offering a bounty on the original or posting a comment asking for an update?

Comment: Can only second @tohster 's comment - the lines are blurred between "enterprise" and "customer" software, with employees chatting on facebook about scheduling (yes, my company) and enterprise software companies offering free email/calendar/task software for anyone (not only customers). An update to the original question may be fruitful, but the split into enterprise is not.

Comment: Okay closing topic and adding as comment to original post