# Using a single button for sign-in and sign-up

Tags: website-design, google

What's the best label to put on the OAuth button (google/facebook) which allows both registration and signing in?

We really see little sense of having two separate buttons which does exactly same thing - authenticate the user. However we had a (vary) few customers mailing us to ask how to register as they only see sign-in button. How to label this button so it is more clear and inline with google's branding policies?

Comment: This is why it is recommended to [use descriptive labels](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/labels-or-instructions) like "sign-in or register" as that literally explains what the buttons is for. Also, a bit off-topic but maybe relevant for you: [Using "Sign in" vs using "Log in"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

"Continue with Google"

"Continue with Facebook"

If the user already has the account, he/she will be logged in. If not, The user will have a new account and logged in

Answer (score 1):

"*Continue with...*" seems to be the best and most comprehensive label for when the use-case includes both Signing in and Signing up.

Saying that, you should also consider guidelines for each of those platforms.

Consider that users rely on consistent experience across different use-cases: they will look for the button that looks and feels familiar, so the less change you make, the better it generally is. Guidelines are a good help for that:

- [Google says](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) you should use "*Sign in with Google*" with their button (or "*Sign up with Google*" when the use-cases are separated);
- [Facebook says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button) you should use "*Continue with Facebook*" on their button for both use-cases;
- [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple#Creating-a-custom-Sign-in-with-Apple-button) you should use "*Continue with Apple*" if it's united and "*Sign in with Apple*"/"*Sign-up with Apple*" if they're separated.